# jQuery doesn't work on page loaded by ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

My jQuery code:

```
var menu = 0;
var link = "";
var column = 2;

jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
$('body').css('height', $(window).height());
$('body').css('width', 32 + (230*column));

$(".button").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    link = $(this).find('a').attr("href");

    $("#menu").css({'left':event.pageX});
    $("#menu").css({'top':event.pageY});
    $("#menu").find('#gotosite').attr("href", link);
    $("#menu").slideDown();
    menu = 1;
});

$("#zamknij_menu").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#menu").slideUp();
    menu = 0;
});

$("#zbadaj_element").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#menu").slideUp();
    menu = 0;
    $("body").append("<div class=\"column\" id=\"" + column + "\">");
    $("#" + column).html('<img src="load.gif" alt="Please Wait" /><p>Loading... Please Wait</p>');
    $("#" + column).load("robotone.php?url=" + link);

    column++;
    $("body").append("</div>");
    $('body').css('width', 32 + (230*column));
});

$("#openhelp").click(function(event) {
    $("#legend").slideToggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
});
```

This script append div with class column to body and load into it php file. This script work properly with html document, but doesn't work for new columns which were added by this script. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sice those are added dynamically do [Event Delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Example:

```
$(document).on("eventname",'.selector', function(event,ele){
 //Your code goes here
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2):

When you add new HTML elements to the DOM after you've bound your events, those new elements won't be bound.  [The jQuery `.on` function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is designed to address this.  It works in a slightly different way.

Events in the DOM "bubble up" to their parent elements (unless explicitly told not to in code, which you don't appear to be doing).  So, when you "click" an element, you also "click" its parent element, that element's parent, and so on, all the way up to the `body` element and, ultimately, the `document`.  Thus, you can also bind to those parent elements to respond to a click.

The `.on` function does just that, and includes a filter to only respond to events raised to that parent element which are from a specific selector.  So, instead of binding to the child element itself, you can bind to a common parent.  `body` or `document` are often used for this purpose.  Something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.button', function () {
    // your event handling code
});
```

This binds to the click event of `document`, but only responds to that event if the originator of the event was of class `button`.  The end result is the same as if you bound to the click event of the elements of class `button`, but with two distinct differences under the hood:

1. You only create *one* event on the DOM, instead of one for every element of class `button`.  If you have many elements, this results in improved performance.
2. Any elements of class `button` added to the DOM *after* this event is bound are still affected.  As long as they're a child of the common parent (in this case they are, everything is a child of `document`), then their event will still "bubble up" to that parent.  This is often referred to as "deferred events."  Essentially, you can add all the elements you want and they'll still be responded to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 'on' in every event say for ex.,

```
$(".button").on('click',function(event) {
    // code
});
```

Follow this way

Comment: This won't catch new added elements of the `.button` class because it still binds directly to them instead of to a common parent.

Answer (score 0):

`$(selector).click(...)` appends the clickHandler only to the domElements that are already exisiting, you should use `$(selector).on('click', function(){...});` to append the handler also to elements that will be inserted later on...